# Question about the preposition 'у' and the usage of pronouns following it

Tags: грамматика, предлоги

My teacher told me about prepositional cases for nouns and pronouns, and that if a pronoun is preceded by a preposition, then it takes prepositional case. However, in cases such as `у тебя есть...` why is `тебя` not taking the prepositional case of `тебе`?

I do want to point out that I am very new to this language so please do try to explain it in as simple words as possible. Thanks!

Comment: "if a pronoun is preceded by a preposition, then it takes prepositional case" - your teacher is wrong.

Comment: Please do excuse me, my teacher is brilliant she is teaching me from Troika - which is a well-recognised book and it's the book which is giving it out as a rule. She has told me about the exception for this case but I want to understand the reason for this exception.

Comment: @YellowSky can you please elaborate a bit more on this? When do we use тебе and why can we not use the prepositional case after y

Comment: In Russian there are only 6 prepositions that need the prepositional case after them: в (во) 'in', на 'on', о (об, обо) 'about', по 'along, (moving) on the surface of', and при 'at'. The first 2 when used with the prepositional case mean the place, and when used with the accusative case mean the direction to the place: _в воде_ (prep.) 'in the water' — _в воду_ (acc.) 'into the water'. That's all, all the rest of the prepositions are to be followed by the other cases. My guess is, since you're just a beginner, your teacher meant only в and на, the 2 most widely used prepositions.

Comment: my answer:
у кого? - у тебя;
кому? - тебе

Comment: Thanks for elaborating! Can you please put it as an answer as well and I will accept that - so that this thread can be closed.

Comment: "О" can also mean "with" 

"стол о трёх ножак"—A table with three legs

and "по" can mean "after, upon completion" "по окочании работы"—After Work

But these are very rare (as far as I know); so best to forget them :)

Comment: @Yellow Sky "по столу" is Dative, not Prepositional

Comment: How do you determine that a teacher of the first semester is "brilliant" in any sense?

Comment: @KCd I know she is brilliant because I am the one taking classes and I am not in college. Please keep the discussion to the topic and stop commenting on my teachers.

Comment: "if a pronoun is preceded by a preposition, then it takes prepositional case" - that's just a mistake. The right thing is: a pronoun in prepositional case is always preceded by a preposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Russian there are only 5 prepositions that need the prepositional case after them:

> в (во) 'in'
>
> на 'on'
>
> о (об, обо) 'about'
>
> по 'along, (moving) on the surface of'
>
> при 'at'

The first 2 when used with the prepositional case mean the place, and when used with the accusative case mean the direction to the place:

> в воде (prep.) 'in the water' — в воду (acc.) 'into the water'
>
> на земле (prep.) 'on the ground' — на землю (acc.) 'onto the ground'.

That's all, all the rest of the prepositions are to be followed by the other cases. My guess is, since you're just a beginner, your teacher meant only **в** and **на**, the 2 most widely used prepositions.

Comment: strange, I've never heard of nor seen "по" being used to mean moving on the surface of something. Doesn't dative get used for that??

Comment: "по столу" is Dative, not Prepositional, -1

Comment: Besides this, в and на also can govern Locative when meaning place: в лесу, на снегу.

Comment: You wrote there are six prepositions, but specified only five.

Comment: @user31264 - Yes, a typo, corrected.

Answer (score 1):

A little more about "по" with prepositional case:

> По прошествии времени (some time later)
>
> По ком звонит колокол (For whom the bell tolls)
>
> Я скучаю по Вас (instead of "Я скучаю по Вам")

1st is normal, 3rd is a little outdated.

Comment: The third one always grates on my ear.. How outdated is it?

Comment: @UVV http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/hardwords/25_294 I don't think that many people nowadays say so. Yet bookish wisdom seem still approve it. "Скучать" is a funny verb. Sometimes they even say "Скучаю _за_ тобой" (ukrainism?).

Comment: the last on grates at most. My mother in law comes from Bashkortostan and she uses it.. at that time I persuade myself how patient I am ;)